# Acceleration in polar coordinates

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, vectors

Is transverse acceleration always perpendicular to the normal acceleration, in polar coordinates?

Comment: Are you asking whether $\hat{T}\perp\hat{N}$ in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) notation? If so, yes.

Comment: It is just like saying $a_x \perp a_y$ in rectangular coordinates.